# How to pass a list of numbers as a single feature to a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to cluster sentences by clustering the sentence embedding of them taken from fasttext model. Each sentence embedding has 300 dimensions, and I want to reduce them to 50 (say). I tried t-SNE, PCA, UMAP. I wanted to see how Auto Encoder works for my data.

Now passing those 300 numbers for each sentence as separate features to the NN would make sense or they should be passed as a single entity? If so, is there an way to pass a list as a feature to NN?

I tried passing the 300 numbers as individual features and with the output I tried clustering. Could get very few meaningful clusters rest were either noise or clusters with no similar sentences but being grouped (But with other techniques like UMAP I could get far more meaningful clusters in more number). Any leads would be helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried the Universal sentence encoder from tensorflowhub ? if you are trying to make clusters of sentences based on their similarity then using this model would make much sense in my opinion. Previously I had better results using it.

Comment: Hey @Manoj, I haven't tried that yet. Thanks for your suggestion :) Will look into it